# Can we create files in Linux server from front end html page?

Tags: java, php, ajax, linux

I would like to know if we can create files from a html page in browser to the linux server folder?   I have a shell script which creates txt files.. But when i trigger this script from browser using ajax it doesn't create any files.. I gave all permissions to the parent directory but still i dont see file creations nor any error.

```
    test.sh


  echo "first sh"   
  java HelloWorld
  echo "t1 test" > t1s
  if [ ! -f t1s ]
  then
  echo "Shell File is not created .."
  else
  echo "Shell file is created.. "
  fi



  ------
  first.php

  <?php
  $output=shell_exec('sh test.sh');
  echo "Hello Php \r\n";
  echo $output;
  echo "done \r\n";
  ?>

  -----------
  This is the output from command line:

  Hello Php

  hello first sh  Shell file is created..


  done
  ----------------

  This is the output from broswer:

  Hello Php hello first sh Shell File is not created .. done
```

Comment: The short answer is "Yes, you can." For answers relevant to your specific situation, you will need to provide the specific details of your implementation.

Comment: HI... I have updated with the details. Could you check and tell me what changes i have to make. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When executing scripts via your web server, it helps to note that the environment used by your webserver is rarely identical to the environment that you see as a CLI user. For example, the command

```
sh test.sh
```

makes two assumptions: `sh` is in your $PATH, and `test.sh` is in the current working directory. It is very likely that neither of these are true when your webserver tries to run the command.

For better results, try including full paths to both the command and the file. For example:

```
shell_exec('/bin/sh /var/www/html/scripts/test.sh');
```

Finally, check the executable permissions on `test.sh` to be sure that the web user (httpd, or apache, or whatever) has permission to execute that script.

Comment: i have updated the above changes. and it is working fine at command line but when i try from browser it gives no error message nor it creates any file at server..    Could you tell me if we can print the output at file creation line..  i.e.,  capturing what it returns at  "echo "t1 test" > /home/siva/public_html/t1s"  line